# Stock sorting options?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

Is there a way to view the stocks screen that's not just a list of what you have?  Maybe be able to search my stocks for specific items?

Comment: If you use the Masterwork mod, it adds in search options in quite a few useful locations.

Comment: I think the game leaves out a lot of stuff you have no access to just because there is so many junk. (Sperm whale creates on butcher the following parts: teeth, tripe, hearts, meat, bones, sinew, organs, skin, hopes, dreams, soul, etc). You really don't want that clogging up your stocks screen.

Answer (score 1):

DFHack can add search option to Stocks screen, see [dfhack#search](https://github.com/peterix/dfhack#search).

> The search plugin adds search to the Stocks, Animals, Trading,
>   Stockpile, Noble (assignment candidates), Military (position
>   candidates), Burrows (unit list), Rooms, Announcements, Job List and
>   Unit List screens.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use my Improved Stocks Screen plugin for DFHack r3: http://www.bay12forums.com/smf/index.php?topic=125164.0 that makes it easier to find what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

In the stocks screen, use the right arrow key to move to the list of stocks, then `tab` to explode the current group from by-count to by individual item.

At that point you can also zoom to any such item or designate them for dumping, melting or reclaiming.

**NOTE:** You can only do this if your stockpile records are up to date and the item count is lower than the maximum accurate count of your current precision level.